# php encode full url with spaces in arguments

Tags: php, urlencode

I have a url that looks like that

```
http://example.com/index.php?id=111&title=word1 word2 word3
```

I need to encode the spaces before requesting the url with curl.

But how to urlencode the right parts of the url.

`urlencode` and `rawurlencode` encode the slashes of `https` the question mark etc.

Comment: Use parse_url to break the URL into its component parts, and then operate on the query string as required. Use http_build_url to stitch back together.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [parse_url()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) to split the URL into its respective pieces. Use `urlencode()` on the `query` element from the array that `parse_url` returns, then put it back together using [http_build_url](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-url.php).

NOTE: `http_build_url` requires PECL pecl_http >= 0.21.0

Comment: Further use of parse_str and http_build_query are worth mentioning too.

Comment: The query is already partly encoded, wouldn't encoding it again result in the existing &'s and ='s being mistakenly substituted?

Comment: parse_url will return the query arguments as a string `id=111&title=word1 word2 word3` If I urlencode that string i run into the same problem. the `&` and `=` will be encoded..

Comment: If spaces are the *only* issue (i.e. word1 word2 etc. *can't* contain any punctuation) surely a simple regex on the whole thing to replace spaces with + would do the job.

Comment: @Beeblbrox for now spaces are the only issue, but I don't have full control over those urls so i'm trying to build a bullet proof encoding function..

Comment: You're not going to get very far trying to make a bullet proof function to convert unknown query strings that may or may not already be properly/fully encoded.  You'll get a best guess function and that's all you'll get.

Answer (score 0):

Replace white spaces with "+".

Answer (score 0):

As @F21 said,...

```
function fixUrlEncoding(string $url){

    $scheme = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_SCHEME);
    $host   = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);
    $path   = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
    $query  = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY);

    $f = explode('?', $query,2);
    $file  = $f[0];
    $query = $f[1];

    $ini   = $scheme . '://' . $host . $path ;

    // fix encoding
    parse_str($query, $result);
    foreach ($result as $k => $val){
        $result[$k] = urlencode($val);
    }

    $query = $file . '?' . http_build_query($result);

    if (!Strings::startsWith('http', $url)){
        $url = $ini . '?' . $query;
    } else {
        $url = substr($url, strlen($ini)) . '?' . $query;
        $url = $ini . '?' . $query;
    }

    return $url;
}
```

Comment: as of PHP 8, Strings::startsWith('http',$url) can be replace with str_starts_with($url,'http') OR substr($url,0,4)=='http' for users with older versions of PHP and no 'Strings'

Comment: Also, the second instance of "$url = $ini . '?' . $query;" I think should be removed...