# How to encode space only in url encode?

Tags: php

I am trying to use urlencode to replace the spaces with a + sign. For example when i pass this string to urlencode "Hyton Accounting & Consulting LLC"

It encodes it like this..

"Hyton+Accounting+%26+Consulting+LLC"

I don't want it to encode the "&" sign. Just the spaces.  Does anyone know a work around?

Comment: Why don't you want the `&` encoded? That is a reserved character.

Comment: str_repalce(' ','+' ...

Comment: you can just use string replace function str_replace (http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-replace.php)

Comment: You don't really want to *URL encode*, you just want to replace spaces with plusses…?!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/9922407/2943403

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-replace.php) to replace only space:

```
$strParam = str_repalce(' ','+', $strParam);
```